# ObjectDataSource Not Binding Properly To GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, objectdatasource

This is probably something simple, just need some fresh eyes. It's very long, but I wanted to give full context. I'm trying to show a GridView that uses an ObjectDataSource. The ODS returns a DataTable. The DT is constructed from the query result of an MSSQL stored procedure. The problem is that my ASP BoundField is complaining at me for wanting a field that isn't in the data source...but it definitely is. When I leave out the aforementioned field, the grid shows fine, but when I press "Delete", an id of 0 is sent to my ODS, not the one that actually deletes the records, 70. I haven't tried updating yet, but I imagine that doesn't work if the other two don't. What am I doing wrong?

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    CssClass="table" 
    DataSourceID="ExcludeODS" 
    EnableViewState="True" 
    ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" 
    ID="ExcludeGridView" 
    runat="server">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RuleKey" HeaderText="Rule Key"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field" HeaderText="Field"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton 
                    runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"> Edit</span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton 
                    runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Delete" 
                    OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')){ return false; };"><span class="fa fa-trash"> Delete</span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"></EditRowStyle>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

**ObjectDataSource (.ASPX):**

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
    runat="server" 
    ID="ExcludeODS" 
    DeleteMethod="CtDeleteExcludeRules" 
    InsertMethod="CtAddExcludeRules" 
    SelectMethod="CtGetExcludeRules" 
    TypeName="CustomerTypeRules.DAL.CtExcludeRules" 
    UpdateMethod="CtUpdateExcludeRules">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" ></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ruleKey" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="field" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter 
            ControlID="RuleDropDown" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
            DefaultValue="null" 
            Name="ruleKey" 
            Type="String">
        </asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="field" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**ObjectDataSource (.CS):**

```
public DataTable CtGetExcludeRules(
    string ruleKey // Length: 255
)
{
    SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(_connectString);
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "CT_Get_ExcludeRules",
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Connection = dbConn
        };

    command.Parameters.Add(
        "@RuleKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255
    ).Value = ruleKey ?? "";

    dbConn.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(dt);

    dbConn.Close();
    da.Dispose();

    return dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? dt : new DataTable{Columns = { "ruleKey", "field" }, Rows = { "No results" }};
}

public bool CtDeleteExcludeRules(
    int id,
    string userId // Length: 50
)
{
    using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection(_connectString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(
            "CT_Delete_ExcludeRules", dbConn
        ))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                "@Id", SqlDbType.Int
            ).Value = id;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                "@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50
            ).Value = userId ?? "";

            dbConn.Open();

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        }
    }
}

public bool CtUpdateExcludeRules(
    int id,
    string field, // Length: 50
    string userId // Length: 50
)
{
    using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection(_connectString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(
            "CT_Update_ExcludeRules", dbConn
        ))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                "@Id", SqlDbType.Int
            ).Value = id;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                "@Field", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50
            ).Value = field;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                "@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50
            ).Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                      ?? "";

            dbConn.Open();

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Stored procedures:**

```
[dbo].[CT_Get_ExcludeRules]
@RuleKey varchar(255) = ''
AS
SELECT * FROM [Interface].[dbo].[CT_ExcludeRules] WHERE RuleKey = @RuleKey;


[dbo].[CT_Delete_ExcludeRules]
@Id int,
@UserId varchar(50)
as

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
BEGIN TRY  

    insert into CT_ExcludeRules_History
    select Id,RuleKey,Field,@UserId,'Delete',getdate()
    from CT_ExcludeRules
    where Id = @Id

    delete from [dbo].[CT_ExcludeRules]
    where Id = @Id

    Commit
END TRY 


[CT_Update_ExcludeRules]
@Id int,
@Field varchar(50),
@UserId varchar(50)
as

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
BEGIN TRY  
    Update [dbo].[CT_ExcludeRules]
    set Field = @Field
    where Id = @Id

    insert into CT_ExcludeRules_History
    select Id,RuleKey,Field,@UserId,'Update',getdate()
    from CT_ExcludeRules
    where Id = @Id

    Commit
END TRY
```

**Table design:**

### [image: Table design]

**GET stored procedure example:**

### [image: Example of GET stored procedure]

**DataTable Rows Results View (also the same array that is retrieved by the data source's OnSelected event):**

### [image: Array retrieved by the data source]

**Values passed to data source after clicking "Delete":**

### [image: Values passed to data source after clicking "Delete"]

Trying to add an Id column to the GridView gives me this error message:

> A field or property with the name 'Id' was not found on the selected
>   data source.

I don't need an id column, I just want to delete and update like a normal GridView!

**RESOLUTION:**

Thanks to user "sea-charp" below for seeing what was missing. I needed to replace { "ruleKey", "field" } with { "id", "ruleKey", "field" } in order for my data source to recognize the "Id" property. Once that was recognized, I was able to add "Id" in the DataKeyNames attribute of my GridView, which fully enabled my deletion method via the proper Id of 70 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
command.Parameters.Add(
        "@RuleKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255
    ).Value = ruleKey ?? "";
```

Try this

```
command.Parameters.Add("@RuleKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
command.Parameters("@RuleKey").Value = ruleKey ?? "";
```

Looks like you're getting the error because you have this as part of your return syntax:

```
DataTable{Columns = { "ruleKey", "field" }, Rows = { "No results" }};
```

... which returns a table with no ID when there are no results - possibly because of the command parameter syntax you're using.

Comment: Your original suggestion wasn't the fix for me. It was your last sentence, when you mentioned I wasn't providing an ID column when there were no results. Once I updated it to { "id", "ruleKey", "field" }, suddenly my data source recognized "Id" again. Zero was still coming through with deleting, but after I added my newly-discovered "Id" field in the DataKeyNames attribute of my GridView, the correct id was being passed. Finally! I don't understand why GridView can't use a property unless it's in all possible return scenarios, but I'm thankful you kickstarted my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Funny, I was going to suggest you add the ID as a key field but wasn't sure if it would impact your results. Glad you gut it resolved!